# How to set CultureInfo when using WebApplicationFactory

Tags: asp.net-core

I'd like to write an integration test for an asp.net core project, that fails when the server is started with an unsupported culture. Is it possible to make WebApplicationFactory start the TestServer with a given CultureInfo?

I'm using NET8.

Comment: Have you tried setting the current culture in the test setup? Or overriding the host configuration by overriding ConfigureWebHosts? In that method you can [configure localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-localization-middleware) just like you would in the real application.

Comment: I have you tried setting the current culture in the test setup. That does not work. But I haven't tried the localization middleware. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to test? In an application (or thread) there are two cultures involved, `CurrentCulture` controls parsing and formatting while `CurrentUiCulture` controls the display language and localization resources.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's the CurrentCulture. The web application is a facade for some old components that I do not control, and they need to run under da-dk culture. I'd like to test that this culture is set during the request, even if the tests are run under a different culture.